# Is there a way to attach a Remote Event Receiver to all the custom lists inside a site collection + can i test the RER without having Azure ServiceBus

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, office-365, provider-hosted-app, azure

I have the following:-

1. Sharepoint Online.
2. Visual Studio 2015.
3. Azure free trial account.

now i want to do the following:-

1. Develop a remote event receiver which will get fired when items are added inside custom lists that are found under a site collection.

so i did these steps:-

1. i create a new sharepoint addin project:-

[image]

2. i specify its type as Provider-Hosted, and i add the url for our Developer site collection:-

[image]

3. after that i chose the following:-

   - version = SP online
   - type = ASP.NET MVC
   - Authntication = Windows Azure.
4. after that i set the **Handle App Installed** and **HandleAppUninstalling** properties to True.
5. this will create a new service file, where i added this code, mainly to update the list items' titles after that items are added:-

> ```
> private const string ReceiverName = "ItemAddedEvent";
> private const string ListName = "tg";
>
> public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
> {
>
>     SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();
>
>     switch (properties.EventType)
>     {
>         case SPRemoteEventType.AppInstalled:
>             HandleAppInstalled(properties);
>             break;
>         case SPRemoteEventType.AppUninstalling:
>             HandleAppUninstalling(properties);
>             break;
>         case SPRemoteEventType.ItemAdded:
>             HandleItemAdded(properties);
>             break;
>     }
>
>
>     return result;
> }
>
>      private void HandleAppInstalled(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
>
>     {
>
>          using (ClientContext clientContext =
>
>              TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties, false))
>
>         {
>
>             if (clientContext != null)
>
>            {
>
>                List myList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(ListName);
>
>                clientContext.Load(myList, p => p.EventReceivers);
>
>                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
>
>
>
>                bool rerExists = false;
>
>
>
>               foreach (var rer in myList.EventReceivers)
>
>               {                        
>
>                    if (rer.ReceiverName == ReceiverName)
>
>                    {
>
>                        rerExists = true;
>
>                       System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Found existing ItemAdded receiver at " 
>
>                           + rer.ReceiverUrl);
>
>                    }
>
>              }
>
>
>
>               if (!rerExists)
>
>               {
>
>                  EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation receiver =
>
>                       new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation();
>
>                  receiver.EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemAdded;
>
>
>
>                    //Get WCF URL where this message was handled
>
>                    OperationContext op = OperationContext.Current;
>
>                     Message msg = op.RequestContext.RequestMessage;
>
>
>
>                   receiver.ReceiverUrl = msg.Headers.To.ToString();
>
>
>
>                     receiver.ReceiverName = ReceiverName;
>
>                    receiver.Synchronization = EventReceiverSynchronization.Synchronous;
>
>                    myList.EventReceivers.Add(receiver);
>
>
>
>                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
>
>
>
>                   System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Added ItemAdded receiver at "
>
>                             + msg.Headers.To.ToString());
>
>              }
>
>           }
>
>      }
>
>     }
>   private void HandleAppUninstalling(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
>
>      {
>
>          using (ClientContext clientContext =
>
>             TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties, false))
>
>        {
>
>            if (clientContext != null)
>
>           {
>
>               List myList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(ListName);
>
>                clientContext.Load(myList, p => p.EventReceivers);
>
>              clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
>
>
>
>              var rer = myList.EventReceivers.Where(
>
>                   e => e.ReceiverName == ReceiverName).FirstOrDefault();
>
>
>
>                 try
>
>                 {
>
>                     System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Removing ItemAdded receiver at "
>
>                             + rer.ReceiverUrl);
>
>
>
>                    //This will fail when deploying via F5, but works
>
>                     //when deployed to production
>
>                    rer.DeleteObject();
>
>                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
>
>
>
>                }
>
>                 catch (Exception oops)
>
>                 {                            
>
>                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(oops.Message);                     
>
>
>                 }
>
>
>
>            }
>
>       }
>
>    }
>
>
>
>  private void HandleItemAdded(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
>
>  {
>
>        using (ClientContext clientContext =
>
>            TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
>
>          {
>
>            if (clientContext != null)
>
>           {
>
>               try
>
>               {                        
>
>                   List photos = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(
>
>                      properties.ItemEventProperties.ListId);
>
>                     ListItem item = photos.GetItemById(
>
>                        properties.ItemEventProperties.ListItemId);
>
>                    clientContext.Load(item);
>
>                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
>
>
>
>                     item["Title"] += "\nUpdated by RER " +
>
>                         System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
>
>                     item.Update();
>
>                     clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
>
>                 }
>
>                 catch (Exception oops)
>
>                {                        
>
>                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(oops.Message);
>
>               }
>
>            }
>
>
>
>         }
>
>
>
>  }
> ```

6. i went to the `AppMenifest.xml`, and i define to attache the RER to Lists of type custom lists, as follow:-
   [image]
7. final step is that under "SharePoint" tab inside the project properties, i define the Azure end point (i have created a free Azure account):-
   [image]
8. i Build >> Run the project, where i get this message to attach the RER to a custom list named "tg" which i have already created:-
   [image]
9. now i trust the addin >> i add a new item inside the "tg" list, and its title got updated.. GREAT things is working at this point.

But i face these 2 issues:-

**First Issue**

1. Now in my case i want to attach the RER to all the custom lists and not to a specif custom list. so inside the `AppMenifest.xml` i change the setting from List to Site collection as follow:-

[image]

2. now i build and run the project , where i got this message :-

[image]

3. now I trust the addin, but when i add a new item inside the "tg" custom list its title did not chnage!!.

**so my first question is how i can attach the RER to all the custom lists inside my site collection ?**

**Second issue**

When i remove the end point settings inside the debugging section,and i build and run the application, i got this error when Visual Studio try to upload/install the addin:-

> ```
> Add-in failed to install, cleaning up...
> Successfully uninstalled the SharePoint Add-in.
> Add-in installation encountered the following errors:
> 12/01/2018 17:21:36
>
> @"Error 1
>         CorrelationId: f7908248-48bb-49e7-ba25-08aeef895123
>         ErrorDetail: The remote event receiver callout failed.
>         ErrorType: Transient
>         ErrorTypeName: Intermittent
>         ExceptionMessage: There was no endpoint listening at https://localhost:44368/Services/AppEventReceiver.svc that could
> ```
>
> accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or
>   SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>               Source: Common
>               SourceName: Common App Deployment
>
> ```
> @"Error 2
>         CorrelationId: f7908248-48bb-49e7-ba25-08aeef895123
>         ErrorDetail: The remote event receiver callout failed.
>         ErrorType: Transient
>         ErrorTypeName: Intermittent
>         ExceptionMessage: There was no endpoint listening at > https://localhost:44368/Services/AppEventReceiver.svc that could
> ```
>
> accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or
>   SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>               Source: Common
>               SourceName: Common App Deployment

**so does this mean that i can not test any provider hosted app unless i have an Azure service bus end point?**
Can anyone advice on the above 2 issues i am facing?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

hm...I wanted to ask very similar question.

What would be the best approach to use in such situation to listen to events in sharepoint list and do something..
I have lists i want to listen to so i can lift and shift data around lists..just like a database table

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to add a receiver only to the existing lists once or to any new lists that are created thereafter as well ?